# print a variable has an add num

Tags: php

Why is there a 1 appended to each printed variable when the following code is run?

```
<?php
$HoldIndex = array("10023", "10024", "10025", "10026");
$i = 1;
foreach ($HoldIndex as $z) 
  {
    ${'M6'.$i} = $z;
    $i++;
  }
echo "<br>"; echo "<br>";
echo print_r($M61); echo "<br>";
echo print_r($M62); echo "<br>";
echo print_r($M63); echo "<br>";
echo print_r($M64); echo "<br>";
?>
type here
```

Output looks like this:

```
100231
100241
100251
100261
```

I did not expect to see a 1 appended to each of the printed vars.

Comment: Because `print_r()` prints its argument and then returns `true`. When you print `true`, it prints as `1`.

Comment: Either get rid of `echo` or use `echo print_r($M61, true)`. The second argument tells `print_r()` to return the string instead of printing it.